# How to get realtime data from MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, real-time, real-time-data

I have set a scheduler every 2 seconds:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
              Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("onezero");
public static void main( String[] args )
{ 
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                try {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
                SearchEURUSD(); 
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }       
    }, 0, 2000);
}
```

No I want this to change to a realtime check in my database. If any change in my database occurs, I want `SearchEURUSD();` to be called. How can I do that?

Comment: *how to do that ?* In MySQL - while changing data set some mark in some service table (for example by trigger). In java - query this service table for the mark is set, if true perform needed action and clear the mark.

Answer (score -1):

initially store the current object into a variable and then use **.equals()**  method to compare. Complete example code:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
              Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("onezero");
    public static void main( String[] args )
    { 
        //Object is your model class
        Object currentObject=null;

        Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           System.out.println("Hello World");
        try{
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
            // initialize dbObject with the object you got from db.
            Object dbObject=objectGotFromDb;
            if(currentObject==null){
             currentObject=dbObject;
            }
            if(!currentObject.equal(dbObject){
            //Current object and db object are not equal
            SearchEURUSD(); 
            //updating the current object with updated db object.
            currentObject=dbObject;
            }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
        }       
    }, 0, 2000);
    }
```